# How to access to the current element with ng-style

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to get access to the current element css properties when I use ng-style

Since the following element:

```
<div ng-style="changeWidth()">
```

Get access to its CSS properties

```
$scope.changeWidth = function(element) {
    return {
       width: element.width() / 2
    }
};
```

Someone knows the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use directives:

```
.directive("getStyle",function(){
  return{
    link:function(scope,element){
      element[0].style.border = "5px dotted #090";
    }        
  }      
});
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/izOrEi?p=preview

One more (directive-scope interaction): http://plnkr.co/edit/uL7N1j?p=preview

Comment: Is it the best workaround? I mean what happen if the changeWidth functions depends on another flag in the scope. Something like: <div ng-style="{flag: changeWidth()}">

Comment: @Lt. yes it is a good practice to put View' behaviour logic in a directives. Here you can see an example of directive <-> scope interaction: http://plnkr.co/edit/uL7N1j?p=preview

Comment: so, I have to base my "logic" in as many directives as necessary?

Comment: @Lt. exactly , but Model's logic put in services . (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services)