# angularjs html tag's style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have some html

```
<div ng-style="multiStyle(row)" ng-repeat="row in search_result | filter:cacheTemplate track by $index">
```

Beforehand I didn't know height of this div. It may be 60px or 80px depending on screen. Is it possible to send into function mutliStyle(row, height) height of this div as an argument? Or to send into this function this div so in my function I can get this height?

Comment: if you are are using bootstrap, you can use the responsive utilities http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities which applies css based on screen size. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MattjeS I don't using bootsrtap. I need to get height of this div in my function to reassign height with new value.

Comment: whats the logic of setting the new height? you could get the height using javascript in the function, if the row had an id, say the index, pass that into the function, multiStyle(row, $index)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use css ?
You could simply write a media query like this

```
@media screen and (max-height: 500px) {
   ...
}
```

Another solution is described here :
[How to access to the current element with ng-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223723/how-to-access-to-the-current-element-with-ng-style)

Comment: I'm already using this. Because of @media I have this problem.

Comment: Did you tried to implement a directive to get element ?