# Get element ng-class AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ive have an element like this:

```
<div class="someclasses" ng-class="{'new-class': function()}">
```

If using `ng-click` we can get the element by passing the `$event`. Like so:

```
<div class="someClasses" ng-click="function($event)">
```

Then get the target element like so:

```
$scope.function = function($event) {
    console.log($event.currentTarget); // Logs the current target element
}
```

However, `ng-class` does not support event object `$event` being passed as a parameter.

So my question is, how can I get the target element where `ng-class` is assigned too?

I cannot use the `angular.element('classname')` selector, as the expression inside the function looks for a classname which is added dynamicly, on the element where the `ng-class` is assigned too.

Comment: Why do you need the element? Maybe there is a better way to do this

Comment: Passing `$event` doesn't make sense for `ng-class` because there isn't any event actually being fired when a class is assigned to an element. The underlying function is expected to return a string instead. Let us know your use-case, and someone may be able to save you.

Comment: Im using the bootstrap collapse component. If a class is present is collapses the div. I tried ng-init aswell, but no luck too. So Im stuck now.

Comment: @31piy Yes, I agree with that. But is there a way I can get the element where the `ng-class` is assigned too?

Comment: @Red but what sets the class that causes it to collapse?

Comment: @FrankModica the class which is used to collapse the element is `.in`

Comment: I mean what code sets that `.in` class? Does it happen during an event, like a click? If so, executing logic at that moment might make sense.

Comment: No, it happens when ng-repeat refreshes and inside the collapse element there are checkboxes with the state `:checked`

Comment: I fixed it however using a mix the accepted awnser and my own logic. And works now.

Comment: Oh ok, you might want to use one-time binding for `ng-class` if you only need the function to run when the element is first repainted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest terms, this is not possible. You will need to write a custom directive to do that, as specified in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223723/how-to-access-to-the-current-element-with-ng-style).

Alternatively, if you have the div under an `ng-repeat` or so, you can manually pass some identifier to your function which will help it in finding the correct info.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
  <div class="someclasses" ng-class="{'new-class': classFunc($index)}">
  ...
</div>
```

This way, the index of the item can be accessed by `classFunc` and it can find the info in `data` accordingly.

Comment: This makes sense, going to try it out. Thanks!